# If radio buttons is checked then display div in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a user form, I am stuck in it bacause I want that if A radio button is checked then display a div.I could not do this as I am little bit weak in javascript. please find my code below.
My button is

```
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="groups[]" value="6"> Head of Distribution Sales
</label>
```

And after selecting the button I want to show this div

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Regions</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="checkbox-list">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="43"> Dhaka North
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="44"> Dhaka South
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="45"> Comilla
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="46"> Chittagong
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="47"> Khulna
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="48"> Mymensingh
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="49"> Sylhet
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="50"> Rangpur
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="51"> Bogra
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="52"> Barisal
                </label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me guys solving this.

Comment: show your jquery code first what you tried

Comment: Is there other no of radio buttons are present? Or it is the only One?

Comment: you need to give the complete HTML structure, If there are more no of Radio buttons are there, then according to that only we have give the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you have to make following changes in your HTML and implement jquery code as snippet.

1. Give id to the div which you want to show/hide.
2. Initially hide div by giving `style="display:none"`
3. place a jquery code to fire on change event on radio button and show/hide div accordingly.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$("input[type='radio'][name='groups[]']").on("change",function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $("#displayDS").show();
  }else{
    $("#displayDS").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="groups[]" value="6"> Head of Distribution Sales
</label>
<br/><br/>
<div class="form-group" style="display:none" id="displayDS">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Regions</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="checkbox-list">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="43"> Dhaka North
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="44"> Dhaka South
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="45"> Comilla
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="46"> Chittagong
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="47"> Khulna
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="48"> Mymensingh
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="49"> Sylhet
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="50"> Rangpur
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="51"> Bogra
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="52"> Barisal
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You sir. You saved my day. @Rahul Patel

Comment: You are welcome mate.. please accept and upvote my answer if it does helped you so other people can also find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I add some IDs to simplifier

```
// HTML
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="myRadio" name="groups[]" value="6"> Head of Distribution Sales
</label>

<div id="yourDiv" class="form-group" style="display:none;"> [... checkboxes ...] </div>


// JS
document.getElementById('myRadio').addEventListener('change', function(){
  document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```js
document.getElementById('myRadio').addEventListener('change', function(){
  document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="myRadio" name="groups[]" value="6"> Head of Distribution Sales
</label>
<div id="yourDiv" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Regions</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="checkbox-list">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="43"> Dhaka North
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="44"> Dhaka South
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="45"> Comilla
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="46"> Chittagong
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="47"> Khulna
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="48"> Mymensingh
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="49"> Sylhet
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="50"> Rangpur
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="51"> Bogra
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="52"> Barisal
                </label>
                <label>
    <input type="radio" name="groups[]" value="6"> Head of Distribution Sales
</label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'your input id') {
        $('#div id').show();           
   }

   else {
        $('#div id').hide();   
   }
});
});
```